# Oxyplot Wpf (How to Pan to Value of X Axis)

Tags: oxyplot

If my graph shows values of 0-100 on x axis, how can I pan x axis to value of 115 from code behind?

Answer (score 1):

Since the Maximum Value (assuming Max is 100, from the description is the OP) of your X Axis is already set (at the point when you want to pan from behind), the first step required would be to change the Maximum of the Axis.

```
 var axis = Model.Axes.First(x => x.Position == OxyPlot.Axes.AxisPosition.Bottom);
 axis.Maximum = 120;
 Model.InvalidatePlot(false);
 axis.Pan(115);
 Model.InvalidatePlot(false);
```

Once the Maximum has been reset, you can use Axis.Pan Method to pan to desired point .

In case, Maximum of your X Axis is already more than the desired value, you can skip the first step.

```
 var axis = Model.Axes.First(x => x.Position == OxyPlot.Axes.AxisPosition.Bottom);
 axis.Pan(115);
 Model.InvalidatePlot(false);
```